# How to check what plugins used to be on a WordPress installation?

Tags: plugins, customization, uninstallation, installation

It's easy to see what plugins are currently disabled through `/wp-admin` — but how could I see what plugins *used* to be on an installation of WordPress and were deleted?

Comment: There's afaik no such possibility. WordPress only keeps track of those which were currently activated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t. WordPress tracks the recently active plugins for a while, but there is no history of deleted plugins.

You could install a logger and track this information in a special place for the future.